# HTML How to draw picture and text when an option is selected?

Tags: html, css

I want to bring up a picture and a body of text below the drop down menu when an option is selected. Would I have to make another HTML document with what I want it to bring up and have it load that new page, or is there a way to do it without having to load a new page for each choice made?

I would like to compare the two things once they're chosen, so it would be a side by side comparison.

Here's basically what I have (I'm new to web development):

```
<select align="left">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
</select>

if (value == "Apple")
{
    <img src ="apple.png"/>
}


<select align="right">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  99% of web development is researching and discovering solutions to your problems.  If you make no attempt to solve the problems yourself you aren't actually going to learn anything of substance.

Comment: Can it be done with HTML and CSS? No. Can it be done other ways? Yes, javascript can be used to do it on the browser or serverside scripting could also be used but would be overkill her.

Comment: What is the body of text? How extensive is it? A few words? A few lines? Several paragraphs?

Comment: @JonP Could I just incorporate javascript into my html code, like nothing to import or use any compiler in specific? (I've only ever used Java before sorry) And it would most likely be a couple of paragraphs with bolding, underlining, etc.

Comment: Javascript is a scripting lanquage, interpreted in place in the browser. No compiler required.  I would go find some basic javascript tutorials and start from there. Javascrtipt is used to manipulate the DOM and responds to events, so it won't work like you have in your question. Also keep in mind java and javascript are VERY different: Java is to javascript as ham is to hamster!

Comment: Haha I like the analogy XD I'll look up a lot on javascript, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normaly I wouldn't go a jQuery approach fo someone who has limited javascript exposure. I will here, because it makes it a fairly trivial solution.

For the un-initiated [jQuery](http://jQuery.com) is a javascript libary that makes DOM navigation and manipulation very easy and irons out some cross platform issues. It is important to have a good understanding of the basics  of jasvascript and not be completely dependant on jquert (or any other library). Have a strong understanding of javascript will enable you to get more out of any given library.

Now on to the code....

**HTML**

```
<div class="column">
  <select class="match">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
  </select>
  <div class="result"><!--Will be used to display results--></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <select class="match">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
  </select>
  <div class="result"><!--Will be used to display results--></div>
</div>

<!-- CSS will be used to hide these -->
<div class="templates">
  <!-- Put your images and text in the appropriate div based on  id
       ID should be the value from the select items --> 
  <div id="Apple">
    <h2>Apple</h2>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFvne6oWopOQ2_GO180lwy0V9w6VkkZcW23O4pIEWZjjIdCcrU" />
    <!--- Put your content here -->
  </div>
  <div id="Bannana">
    <h2>Bannana</h2>
    <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSAUv8_U29YTlfHjGlMLegQH8YfQCozUGcVdqIqH3oxfDeSwucO" />
           <!--- Put your content here -->
  </div>

  <div id="Pear">
    <h2>Pear</h2>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYUDCELQm7ccg3VkCGZSjdCnNu0mrnKsFL4sBS-TRpAly8SfCoZFOAwg" />
            <!--- Put your content here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**Basic CSS**

```
/*Make the columns*/
.column {
  display:inline-block;
  width:48%;
}

/*Hide the templates*/
.templates
{
  display:none;
}
```

**javascript/jQuery**

```
//Will fire when something with class "match" changes
$(".match").change(function(){     
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();

     //Get the html from the template with matching id
     var targetHTML = $("#" + selectedValue).html();
     var parentDiv = $(this).closest(".column");

     //Set html for the results container
     $(parentDiv).find(".result").html(targetHTML);
});
```

Before trying to implement this make sure to read :

- http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/
- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/
- http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Note for my script to work you will need to include the jQuery library, Google has a hosted version, so use that. You will also need to put my script in `$( document ).ready()`

The full version/demo is below.

```js
//Will fire when something with class "match" changes
$(".match").change(function(){     
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();
     //Get the html from the template with matching id
     var targetHTML = $("#" + selectedValue).html();
     var parentDiv = $(this).closest(".column");
     //Set html for the results container
     $(parentDiv).find(".result").html(targetHTML);
});
```

```css
/*Make the columns*/
.column {
  display:inline-block;
  width:48%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

/*Hide the templates*/
.templates
{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column">
  <select class="match">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
    
  </select>
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <select class="match">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
  </select>
  <div class="result"></div>
</div>

<div class="templates">
  <div id="Apple">
    <h2>Apple</h2>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSFvne6oWopOQ2_GO180lwy0V9w6VkkZcW23O4pIEWZjjIdCcrU" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vel facilisis diam. Sed vitae ullamcorper mauris. Donec ac sapien vitae libero vestibulum interdum in finibus magna. Ut venenatis tortor in egestas finibus. Quisque commodo augue quis
      magna posuere, ut facilisis lectus posuere. Morbi sodales interdum tortor eget ornare. Proin sit amet ipsum eget nisi dapibus egestas.</p>
    <p>Sed ultrices leo ut elit consequat tempus. Pellentesque pulvinar lectus sed congue porta. Vivamus ac leo id metus malesuada faucibus. Quisque ac viverra quam, vel aliquet erat. Nulla semper urna eu rutrum sagittis. Vestibulum id magna ligula. Donec
      ac viverra metus. Donec sodales purus nec feugiat pulvinar.</p>
    <p>Sed malesuada sem sed tellus aliquet, vel tempus purus condimentum. Aenean vel est ut metus pellentesque vulputate. Donec eu ipsum suscipit magna maximus maximus. Phasellus ligula libero, tincidunt non laoreet at, interdum vel erat. Nullam sit amet
      aliquet sapien. Vivamus fermentum nisi eu massa vestibulum, ac auctor velit viverra. Duis vitae ligula nisl. Praesent pretium at enim at pulvinar. Vivamus commodo eros a sodales varius. Curabitur sed nisi quis eros vehicula rhoncus et at massa.
      Aenean ut leo neque. Nullam vel ultricies nisl, et porttitor tellus. Praesent sagittis facilisis purus, vitae euismod tellus lacinia at. Phasellus viverra, ante eu efficitur vehicula, nibh neque tempus libero, non tristique nulla risus eu sem. Vivamus
      rhoncus feugiat elementum. Praesent fermentum a lacus ac cursus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="Banana">
    <h2>Bannana</h2>
    <img src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSAUv8_U29YTlfHjGlMLegQH8YfQCozUGcVdqIqH3oxfDeSwucO" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vel facilisis diam. Sed vitae ullamcorper mauris. Donec ac sapien vitae libero vestibulum interdum in finibus magna. Ut venenatis tortor in egestas finibus. Quisque commodo augue quis
      magna posuere, ut facilisis lectus posuere. Morbi sodales interdum tortor eget ornare. Proin sit amet ipsum eget nisi dapibus egestas.</p>
    <p>Sed ultrices leo ut elit consequat tempus. Pellentesque pulvinar lectus sed congue porta. Vivamus ac leo id metus malesuada faucibus. Quisque ac viverra quam, vel aliquet erat. Nulla semper urna eu rutrum sagittis. Vestibulum id magna ligula. Donec
      ac viverra metus. Donec sodales purus nec feugiat pulvinar.</p>
    <p>Sed malesuada sem sed tellus aliquet, vel tempus purus condimentum. Aenean vel est ut metus pellentesque vulputate. Donec eu ipsum suscipit magna maximus maximus. Phasellus ligula libero, tincidunt non laoreet at, interdum vel erat. Nullam sit amet
      aliquet sapien. Vivamus fermentum nisi eu massa vestibulum, ac auctor velit viverra. Duis vitae ligula nisl. Praesent pretium at enim at pulvinar. Vivamus commodo eros a sodales varius. Curabitur sed nisi quis eros vehicula rhoncus et at massa.
      Aenean ut leo neque. Nullam vel ultricies nisl, et porttitor tellus. Praesent sagittis facilisis purus, vitae euismod tellus lacinia at. Phasellus viverra, ante eu efficitur vehicula, nibh neque tempus libero, non tristique nulla risus eu sem. Vivamus
      rhoncus feugiat elementum. Praesent fermentum a lacus ac cursus.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="Pear">
    <h2>Pear</h2>
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRYUDCELQm7ccg3VkCGZSjdCnNu0mrnKsFL4sBS-TRpAly8SfCoZFOAwg" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vel facilisis diam. Sed vitae ullamcorper mauris. Donec ac sapien vitae libero vestibulum interdum in finibus magna. Ut venenatis tortor in egestas finibus. Quisque commodo augue quis
      magna posuere, ut facilisis lectus posuere. Morbi sodales interdum tortor eget ornare. Proin sit amet ipsum eget nisi dapibus egestas.</p>
    <p>Sed ultrices leo ut elit consequat tempus. Pellentesque pulvinar lectus sed congue porta. Vivamus ac leo id metus malesuada faucibus. Quisque ac viverra quam, vel aliquet erat. Nulla semper urna eu rutrum sagittis. Vestibulum id magna ligula. Donec
      ac viverra metus. Donec sodales purus nec feugiat pulvinar.</p>
    <p>Sed malesuada sem sed tellus aliquet, vel tempus purus condimentum. Aenean vel est ut metus pellentesque vulputate. Donec eu ipsum suscipit magna maximus maximus. Phasellus ligula libero, tincidunt non laoreet at, interdum vel erat. Nullam sit amet
      aliquet sapien. Vivamus fermentum nisi eu massa vestibulum, ac auctor velit viverra. Duis vitae ligula nisl. Praesent pretium at enim at pulvinar. Vivamus commodo eros a sodales varius. Curabitur sed nisi quis eros vehicula rhoncus et at massa.
      Aenean ut leo neque. Nullam vel ultricies nisl, et porttitor tellus. Praesent sagittis facilisis purus, vitae euismod tellus lacinia at. Phasellus viverra, ante eu efficitur vehicula, nibh neque tempus libero, non tristique nulla risus eu sem. Vivamus
      rhoncus feugiat elementum. Praesent fermentum a lacus ac cursus.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, like wow. I read up on the $( document ).ready() thing after not getting it to work and then I discovered that I could use

    `function name ( jquery ) {
    }`

and then just call that, but wow thanks that is so cool it works :O and you're right the languages are entirely different. Before I go any farther I'm going to learn all the cool things I can do with jquery. Thanks so much my friend :) that is really impressive

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [JQuery](http://jquery.com).

I am using the selection to show text, but you could use the same technique to show an image instead.

```js
$(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    var $select = $(this);
    $select.next().text($select.val())
  });
})
```

```css
.selector {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selector">
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="selector">
  <select>
    <option></option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option>
    <option value="Pear">Pear</option>
  </select>
  <div></div>
</div>
```